# How do I move apps from Mac desktop to Parallels MacOS virtual machine?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, high-sierra, parallels-desktop

I have a mid 2015 MacBook Pro running Sierra that I need to upgrade at least to High Sierra to run current tax software.  I created a Sierra Virtual Machine with Parallels, hoping to move some apps that apparently will no longer work with High Sierra or higher.  How do I move those applications (right now I am thinking Microsoft Office 2008 and Quicken 2007)?  I tried Google, but all I seem to find is moving an actual VM which is easy.

Comment: idk about Quicken, but Office will very probably need a fresh install, assuming you can still find the installer. Registration might also be an issue, as it's really no longer supported at all.

Comment: You may want to think about getting an external drive and installing high sierra on the drive. boot and run you tax app on the external drive. Less hassle.

Comment: I was able to register a new install of Office 2011 even though it is discontinued.  It was easier than before.  An automated phone process.  No need to speak to a human.

Comment: I've never done this, so I don't feel qualified to answer - but if the VM and host are networked you could try Migration Assistant, that app is sometimes smart enough to collect the files needed to make sure an app functions. For data, either use MA or a shared folder between the VM and host.

Comment: Well I can answer my on question for posterior sake.  Meaning, to not make such of an ass of myself. LOL.  a